# Cast Int as Char * and Back in C

Tags: c, char, int32

Edit: I've edited my question to fix some mistakes and make what I want to do clearer.

I want to convert a 4 byte integer into a char * of length exactly 4 bytes and then back to an int. I understand the integer won't be human readable in char * form.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void intToStr (int32_t i, char ** s) {
    *s = (char *) i;
}

void strToInt (char * s, int32_t * i) {
    *i = (int32_t) s;
}

int main () {

    // Works?

    int32_t a = 5;
    char * b = malloc(4);
    intToStr(a, &b);

    int32_t c = 0;
    strToInt(b, &c);

    printf("%d\n", c);

    // Segfault

    char* s = malloc(64);
    memcpy(s, "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 64);
    memcpy(s + 4, b, 4);
    char * d = malloc(4);
    memcpy(d, s + 4, 4);
    int32_t e = 0;
    strToInt(d, &e);

    printf("%d\n", e);
}
```

This outputs

```
5
Segmentation Fault
```

Instead, I want to be able to cast the int into a char * of length 4, store that into a larger char * (with potentially other data) and then convert it back into an int.

Further Edit:

I've tried something else based on suggestions:

```
void intToStr (int32_t i, char * s) {
    * (int32_t *) s = i;
}

void strToInt (char * s, int32_t * i) {
    * (char **) i = s;
}

int main () {

    int32_t a = 5;
    char * b = malloc(4);
    intToStr(a, b);

    int32_t c = 0;
    strToInt(b, &c);

    printf("%d\n", c);

    char* s = malloc(64);
    memcpy(s, "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 64);
    memcpy(s + 4, b, 4);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    char * d = malloc(4);
    memcpy(d, s + 4, 4);
    int32_t e = 0;
    strToInt(d, &e);

    printf("%d\n", e);

}
```

Which now outputs:

```
[Random Large Int]
0000[?]
[Same Int]
```

Comment: What else were you expecting, and why?

Comment: b is passed by value to `intToStr` so changing s has no effect in main.

Comment: I understand that s will not be human readable but I am expecting to get back my original int. This is for a (convoluted) assignment where I need to fit so many ints into a char * and have only 4 bytes for each.

Comment: In `intToStr`, it changes `s`. But, this is stack local to `intToStr` so the corresponding `b` in `main` will _not_ be changed. But, even if it could be changed, trying to dereference a pointer (i.e. `b` when passed to `memcpy`) with a value of 5 (i.e. an _address_ of 5) is UB (undefined behavior) and would [probably] produce a segfault.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oops my mistake, I switched s to length of 10 for this post not to uselessly clutter the question with 64 0s. Edited now.

Comment: In `intToStr ` both parameters are passed by value. Assigning `s` isn't visible outside that function, you'd need a double pointer for that and then you'd have a dangling pointer to a local variable that no longer exists. If you malloc 10 bytes it's not generally a good idea to try and copy 64 bytes to that space. There's also no variable named `s` in `main` that I can see. Are you sure this exact code compiles?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Fixed the variable naming mistakes. How then would I go about doing this? I'm all out of ideas...

Comment: Do you want `intToStr` to do what `sprintf` with `%d` does?

Comment: @CraigEstey No, using sprintf would mean one char for each digit in the integer. I want the integer to take exactly 4 bytes.

Comment: Hmm ... If you want the _binary_ value (of `i`) to end up in `b` (in `main`), I'd change: `s = (char *) i;` to `*(int32_t *) s = i;`

Comment: Just use `memcpy()` instead of all that casting?

Comment: @Shawn Thank you very much that actually works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To access `int` binary representation as `char`s it is enougt to:

```
int x ;
char *c = (char *)&i;
```

or to copy use `memcpy`

```
int x  = something;
char c[sizeof(x)];

memcpy(c, &x, sizeof(x));
```

But to do this in the opposite direction you need to `memcpy` the `char` array into an `int` number. Otherwise, you might violate strict-aliasing rules

```
int x ;
char c[sizeof(x)];

/* .... */
memcpy(&x, c, sizeof(x));
```

Comment: Based on an earlier comment on the question by @Shawn I'm using memcpy both ways. It works, but is there anything wrong/risky with that?

Comment: @AnAssembler no, it is safe  if you do not access objects outside their bounds and 100% portable. Also most modern compilers will not actually call the `memcpy`